# What to do when people change their questions to something completely different?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the etiquette for changing the substance of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48345/what-is-the-etiquette-for-changing-the-substance-of-a-question)

See the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3271537/revisions) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271537/how-to-format-add-related-resources-or-links), and the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3245689/revisions) of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245689/using-ifileoperation-in-delphi-7).

In the second question, the user gets warned by a moderator to not edit his questions.
The moderator restores the former revision on the second question.

But on the first question, the user has done the same, but then a day earlier.
I can't restore revisions, so how do I contact a moderator that can?

Can you split someone else's question on his/her behalf in two questions?

Comment: I do not understand the edit. Is this some kind of humor?

Comment: @mafutrct: It has to do with [Paul the Octopus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_octopus). Didn't Germany [forgive](http://news.yahoo.com/s/ap/20100706/ap_on_re_eu/eu_germany_octopus_oracle_world_cup_2) him yet?

Comment: Didn't realize the freaky question title was an edit.  WTH?

Comment: @Will It's [Weblog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/weblog), a well known Meta phenomenon.

Comment: I am not a phenomenon. And stop misspelling my name.

Comment: This is similar to, if not a duplicate of [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way to tackle such a case is to flag the moderators for attention. Most probably they will rollback the question, lock it, and throw away the key.

> I can't restore revisions, so how do I contact a moderator that can?

[alt text http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/2722/flagmods.png](http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/2722/flagmods.png)

---

**EDIT:** Note that with 4k rep, you should be able to rollback other people's posts as well. Just do it when you see something naughty. You'll even [get a badge for that](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/4/cleanup).

Comment: That "freehand" circle looks suspiciously smooth and unpixelated. Did you use some fancy photoshop to draw your freehand circles for you?

Comment: No photoshops. I just have a steady hand... As for the unpixillation, it's probably because I use a Mac :)

Comment: @devinb: I smell a tablet and stylus!! ;-)

Comment: /me slaps forehead: never did the association with flag as a verb (only as a noun synonym to banner). 

@Daniel: thx for the quick answer!

Comment: moderator http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will restored a previous version for the first question and locked it.